# Regex to extract all matching values from starts with and ends with

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex

I have a html page as string like below,

```
  "<div id="app">
    <section>
      <esi:include src="http://example.com/LICENSE" />
    </section>
    <section>
      <esi:include src="http://test.com/LICENSE" />
    </section>
  </div>"
```

From the above string, need to extract all esi tags(value for src will be dynamic). So I need to  regex to extract all matching tags. Example Regex to start with `<esi:include` and ends with `/>`.

Expected output is,

```
[<esi:include src="http://example.com/LICENSE" />, <esi:include src="http://test.com/LICENSE" />]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this solution:

```
str = new String('<div id="app"><section><esi:include src="http://example.com/LICENSE" /></section><section><esi:include src="http://test.com/LICENSE" /></section></div>');    
array = str.match(/<esi:include(\s+(.*?)\s*\/>)/g);    
console.log(array);
```

Comment: This is working if html is multiline. But in my serverside rendering entire html will be in single line. "<div id="app"><section><esi:include src="http://example.com/LICENSE" /></section><section><esi:include src="http://test.com/LICENSE" /></section></div>". Please provide soln for all case.

Comment: I-ve modified the solution to use the non-greedy repeat (.*?). This matches the shortest string possible between the spaces...